# Apache webserver status in Ubuntu

Tags: apache, ubuntu, webserver, devops

I have installed apache webserver in my Ubuntu machine and changed port to 8080 (/etc/apache2/apache2.conf, /etc/apache2/000-default.conf) and able to successfully load test page in browser

Using below commands for administration (installed w3m as well):

```
sudo apache2ctl start
sudo apache2ctl stop
sudo apache2ctl status
```

However, sudo apache2ctl status is giving below error:

```
w3m: Can't load http://localhost:80/server-status
```

**I guess apache2ctl status is picking up default port instead of 8080. Can anyone please guide where to change that**

Answer (score 0):

You have not mentioned what did you change in apache2.conf file and 000-default.conf.
you need to set the value of `Listen 8080` in apache2.conf and if you have defined virtual host you need to set the opening virtual-code tag as `<VirtualHost *:8080>`

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes I have added the same and able to view index page in browser with port 8080. But the problem is, sudo apache2ctl status is giving error: w3m: Can't load http://localhost:80/server-status. Is there a config file where I need to specify the port command pickups up for checking server-status

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on changing it to port 8080, it lives inside the `/usr/sbin/apache2ctl` file. Just edit and search for `STATUSURL=`.

Is there a reason you are using port 8080, though?

In your `/etc/sites-enabled/000-default.conf` (hopefully you have it enabled), add the following lines **above** the `<VirtualHost *:80>` line near the top. This will create an override/short-circuit for localhost ONLY.

```
<VirtualHost localhost:80>  #(or use 8080)
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html
</VirtualHost>
```

Make sure port 80 is enabled in `/etc/apache2/ports.conf`. You should see:

```
Listen 80
```

and/or

```
Listen 8080
```

and restart server:

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2.service
```

then try: `sudo apache2ctl status` again..

This also works if you have a redirect inside VirtualHost for <*:80> (mine redirects everything to port :443/SSL), the added lines above will pickup the localhost VirtualHost (first) amd allow the use of `http://localhost/` type urls which of course will also allow `apache2ctl` to work for localhost http calls.